# How to convert `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef` to `CVMetalTextureCacheRef`?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, metal, gpuimage

I need to convert the following code in `GPUImage` pod from OpenGL to Metal, is that possible to do that?

```
CVReturn err = CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, [self context], NULL, &_coreVideoTextureCache);
```

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
CVMetalTextureCacheRef CV_NULLABLE * CV_NONNULL _coreMetalVideoTextureCache = (CVMetalTextureCacheRef CV_NULLABLE * CV_NONNULL)_coreVideoTextureCache;
CVReturn err = CVMetalTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice(), NULL, _coreMetalVideoTextureCache);
```

Comment: Well, it is likely that you are doing something incorrectly, but it is not at all clear what that might be from your code. First off, why would you call MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() and just pass it into the texture cache create function? You need to hold on to the Metal instance in your view controller or toplevel object, this is the metal ref that you would use to send buffers to the GPU and so on. You cannot just allocate the metal device instance and deallocate it right away. How exactly is your code failing?

Comment: The way my code fails is it returns `err`.
Because I have no experience of OpenGL and Metal, I probably do it wrong. I think it might be impossible to convert it, and I shouldn't, too. What I should do is just using `CVMetalTextureCacheRef` consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Your pointer cast is incorrect. You can just pass the address of the `CVMetalTextureCacheRef` directly:

```
CVMetalTextureCacheRef coreMetalVideoTextureCache = NULL;

CVReturn err = CVMetalTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                         NULL,
                                         MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice(),
                                         NULL,
                                         &coreMetalVideoTextureCache);
```

This does assume you're running on a physical device. This won't work in the iOS Simulator prior to iOS 13 and macOS 10.15.